# Using E6 (microdegress) latitude/longitude data format in R

Tags: r, latitude-longitude

I am trying to project latitude/longitude data on a US map. The problem is that my latitude/longitude data is coded in E6 (microdegrees), but R uses a different format (referenced to Greenwich and equator).

My coordinates are here:

`MySpots <- data.frame(latitude=c(35710268, 40764471, 44856323, 42358323, 45522763), longitude=c(4211445105,4220985439,4201615643, 4223905366, 4172310312))`

```
library(ggplot2);
library(maps)

#load US map data
all_states <- map_data("state")
# this is what you get when you check coordinates of all_states. US is west of Greenwich so long data is always negative 
long      lat group order  region subregion
-87.46201 30.38968     1     1 alabama      <NA>
-87.48493 30.37249     1     2 alabama      <NA>
-87.52503 30.37249     1     3 alabama      <NA>
-87.53076 30.33239     1     4 alabama      <NA>

#plot all states with ggplot
p <- ggplot()

p <- p + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),colour="white", fill="grey10" )

p


# Now I try to project my data
p <- p + geom_point(data=MySpots, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, size = Cost), color="coral1")
p <- p + geom_text( data=MySpots, hjust=0.5, vjust=-0.5, aes(x=longitude, y=latitude, label=Stars), colour="gold2", size=4 )

p
```

Is there an easy way to translate my data to format supported by R? or vice versa so that I can project my E6 coordinates with R mapping tools?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,  the formula for E6 (Microdegrees) is: Decimal Degrees * 1e6

Now, if R doesn't use Decimal Degrees, but yet another format, use one of the conversion formulas on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#Putting_it_all_together to switch to whatever format you want.

```
MySpots2 = MySpots / 1e6;
```

To further clarify, I checked the map library and it appears to use decimal degrees, so the conversion above should be everything you need.